# How to hide or remove the child component that rendered by parent component in a template loop of html in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

```
<template>
    <template for:each={cmpList} for:item="ele">
        <div key={ele.id} class={ele.id}>
            {ele.id}
            <c-stopwatch childid={ele.id}></c-stopwatch>
        </div>
    </template>
    <lightning-button label="add" onclick={addNew} ></lightning-button>
</template>
```

///  JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class Stopwatchparent extends LightningElement {
    @track showStopwatch = false;
    @track cmpList = [{id: 1}];

    addNew(){
        this.showStopwatch = true;
        this.cmpList.push({id : this.cmpList.length +1});
    }
    
}
```

//  child js file of child component

```
import { LightningElement, track ,api} from 'lwc';



export default class Stopwatch extends LightningElement {
    @api childid 
    @track showStartBtn = true;
    @track showCloseBtn = false;
    @track showSaveBtn = true;
    @track timeVal = '00:00:00';
    @track submitLWC = false;



    submitBtn() {
      console.log(this.key)
      alert("I am an alert box!");
        this.submitLWC = true;
        this.showSaveBtn = false;
    }

    cancelBtn() {
      alert("I am an alert box!");
        this.submitLWC = false;
        this.showSaveBtn = true;

    }

    closeAction() {
       this.showCloseBtn = false;
     }
// to close the child
CloseHandler() {
  
                     //////   onclick click of the close button this method will get fired ,need to close the particular child (not all child)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @sfdcfox for answering this question.

I fixed this yesterday in simple way

Using filter method .. i just filtered out the array

```
// stopwatchparent
handleClose(event) {
   this.cmpList = this.cmpList.filter(function (item){
      return item.id !== Event.detail
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to communicate via an event.

Here's a quick [copy-paste-fix](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/75N7okaY3GwS1yBYRytq/src/app.js?p=stories) for you.

---

```
// stopwatch
// to close the child
handleCloseClick() {
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close', { detail: { id: this.childid }}))
                    //////   onclick click of the close button this method will get fired ,need to close the particular child (not all child)
  }
```

---

```
// stopwatchparent
handleClose(event) {
  this.cmpList.splice(this.cmpList.findIndex(item => item.id === event.detail.id ), 1)
  this.cmpList = this.cmpList.map((item, id) => ({...item, id: id+1 }));
}
```

---

```
<!-- stopwatchparent.html -->
<c-stopwatch childid={ele.id} onclose={handleClose}></c-stopwatch>
```